# Group action on Artin ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, invariant-theory

Let $k$ be a field and $A$ is a finite dimensional commutative $k$-algebra. Suppose a finite group $G$ acts on $A$ by automorphisms. Then $G$ acts on $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$. Suppose $A^G=\{a \in A | ga=g \text{ for any } g \in G \}$ is isomorphic to $k$. Is action on $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ transitive under such assumptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true. Partition $\operatorname{Spec} A$ in to orbits $O_1,\cdots,O_n$ under the $G$ action. Then on each orbit $O_i$, define the regular function $f_i$ which assigns to each point in the orbit the value $1$ and $0$ to all other points. Then each $f_i$ is invariant under the $G$ action on $A$ and all $f_i$ are mutually orthogonal idempotents, so $A^G\cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^{i=n} Af_i$, and each $Af_i$ contains a copy of $k$. If $A^G\cong k$, then $n=1$ so there's only one orbit and thus $G$ acts transitively on $\operatorname{Spec} A$.

Comment: It is not clear for me why such $f_i$ exist.

Comment: Here are two distinct proofs. 1: Pick generators of $A$ as a $k$-algebra. This embeds $\operatorname{Spec} A\hookrightarrow \Bbb A^n_k$ for some $n$. By polynomial interpolation, there are polynomial functions on $\Bbb A^n_k$ which evaluate to 1 on any single point and 0 elsewhere. Pull these back to $\operatorname{Spec} A$ and take sums. 2: As $A$ is artinian, it's spectrum is discrete, so the structure sheaf is just the direct sum of the stalks. Every stalk is a $k$-algebra and thus contains a copy of $k$. You can construct the same functions which take the value 1 on a single point as in 1.

Comment: Put a third way, the fact that $A$ is artinian implies it's a finite product of local artinian rings $A\cong A_1\times\cdots\times A_m$. Then the $1$ of each $A_i$ gives the function on $\operatorname{Spec} A$ which evaluates to 1 at the point corresponding to the unique maximal ideal of $A_i$ and 0 at all other points.

Comment: Thanks! Can this be generalized to something like this: if a finite groups $G$ acts on "good ring" $A$ orbits of the $Spec (A)$ are in bijection with $Spec (A^G)$?

Comment: Yes, this is general and you don't need any "good ring" assumptions. See [here](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~mmustata/appendix.pdf) for example. The fancy way to say this is that the quotient of $\operatorname{Spec} A$ under the action of a finite group $G$ is $\operatorname{Spec} (A^G)$